# How to do Target System Requirements test before VS 2010 Setup projects c#

Tags: c#, installation, setup-deployment, performance-testing

I have an application that needs to use Oracle 32bit version. I understand, I can add this as prerequisite and if it's not already installed on Target machine, it will be downloaded and installed its done.

**Actually My Requirement is** " I need to do system performance test like **ram size, processor speed, Mouse Availability, keyboard Availability, printer Availability, system maximum screen resolutions support..etc.**"

Is there any possibility that i test all information before setup?

I'm new to Deploy a project could you please tell me where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you can use these individual functions , but here are the functions to check different thing :

```
        //Get system RAM
        private double GetSystemRam()
        {
            var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_ComputerSystem");
            double total_Ram_Bytes = 0;
            foreach (ManagementObject Mobject in searcher.Get())
            {
                total_Ram_Bytes = (Convert.ToDouble(Mobject["TotalPhysicalMemory"]));
                Console.WriteLine("RAM Size in Giga Bytes: {0}", total_Ram_Bytes / 1073741824);

            }
            return total_Ram_Bytes;
        }


        //Get system processor speed
        private int GetprocessorSpeed()
        {
            var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select MaxClockSpeed from Win32_Processor");
            int processorSpeed = 0;
            foreach (var item in searcher.Get())
            {
                processorSpeed = Convert.ToInt32(item["MaxClockSpeed"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Processor Speed is(GHz):" + processorSpeed);
            }
            return processorSpeed;
        }


        //Get system maximum resolution
        private void GetMaxResolution()
        {
            using (var searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM CIM_VideoControllerResolution"))
            {
                var results = searcher.Get();
                UInt32 maxHResolution = 0;
                UInt32 maxVResolution = 0;

                foreach (var item in results)
                {
                    if ((UInt32)item["HorizontalResolution"] > maxHResolution)
                        maxHResolution = (UInt32)item["HorizontalResolution"];

                    if ((UInt32)item["VerticalResolution"] > maxVResolution)
                        maxVResolution = (UInt32)item["VerticalResolution"];
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Max Supported Resolution " + maxHResolution + "x" + maxVResolution);
            }
        }


        //Check for availability of keyboard 
        private bool IsKeyboardAvailable()
        {
            bool isKeyboardAvailable = false;
            var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_Keyboard");

            List<string> keyBoardName = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in searcher.Get())
            {
                keyBoardName.Add(Convert.ToString(item["Name"]));
                Console.WriteLine("KeyBoard name is :" + item["Name"]);
                isKeyboardAvailable = true;
            }
            return isKeyboardAvailable;
        }


        //Check for availability of printer
        private bool IsPrinterAvailable()
        {
            bool isPrinterAvailable = false;
            var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Printer");
            List<string> printerName = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in searcher.Get())
            {
                printerName.Add(item["Name"].ToString().ToLower());
                Console.WriteLine("Printer name is :" + item["Name"]);
                isPrinterAvailable = true;
            }
            return isPrinterAvailable;
        }


        //Check for availability of mouse
        private bool IsMouseAvailable()
        {
            bool isMouseAvailable = false;
            var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_PointingDevice");
            List<string> mouseType = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in searcher.Get())
            {
                mouseType.Add(item["Name"].ToString().ToLower());
                Console.WriteLine("Mouse type is :" + item["Name"]);
                isMouseAvailable = true;
            }
            return isMouseAvailable;
        }
```

**NOTE:** I am just use Console.WriteLine so you can see the values and also using LIST so if you want you can further use that items.

Also read some articles like [How To Get Hardware Information (CPU ID, MainBoard Info, Hard Disk Serial, System Information , ...)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17973/How-To-Get-Hardware-Information-CPU-ID-MainBoard-I)

Comment: thanks for your reply. the main thing i need is how to validate it before setup.

Comment: ya that is imp thing, as i can not have idea what you are doing in your project so i just create separate functions, hope it helps you.

Comment: Probably you can add [custom prerequisite package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429(v=vs.80).aspx) to your installer, and then use <ExternalCheck> in <InstallChecks> element to run custom program for performance testing
(see [ClickOnce Bootstrapper reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229432(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Alexander this is what im searching for.